# Calculate maximum number of open events

Tags: c#, linq, datetime

I have a list of events with an open and close date, like this:

```
DateOpen   | DateClose
-----------|-----------
01.01.2000 | 05.01.2000
02.01.2000 | 02.01.2000
```

So on the 01.01. we have one open event, on the 02.01. we have two open events and from there we have just one open event till the 05.01.

Now the task is to calculate the **maximum number of open events**, in this example it's 2.

I just can't find a good solution for this one, maybe someone else has a good idea. I have all the events in a linq-to-objects list, so ordering, filtering etc is easy.

What have I tried? Nothing, because I don't know where to start :)

Comment: `events.Select(i => events.Where(j => i.DateOpen <= j.DateClose && i.DateClose >= j.DateOpen).Count()).Max()` (I don't program C# these days so may miss something)

Comment: @zerkms: That will probably work. It is O(n^2), but that's probably fine for this application.

Comment: @Gabe: I was thinking of some tree structure but haven't applied them to intervals ever.

Comment: `DateClose` is inclusive or exclusive?

Comment: I have the dates including time, so it goes down to the second. So I think its exclusive even if I don't really understand the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a walk the list solution.  I also include a split the pair of open and close too. (Because I expect that is how your data is stored.)  Since the walk requires open come before close I added in the s and did not just sort on date, and require the order in the creation of the Event object.  This WILL fail if a close comes before an open.

This was written and tested with linqpad.  Copy and paste it as it is and it will run.  Get it (and then love it) at LinqPad.com

I expect this is O(log n) because `OrderBy` should be O(log n).

```
void Main()
{
  List<Event> eList = new List<Event>();
  eList.Add(new Event(new DateTime(2000,1,1),new DateTime(2000,5,1)));
  eList.Add(new Event(new DateTime(2000,2,1),new DateTime(2000,2,1)));

  var datelist = eList.Select(item => new { t = "open", d = item.open, s = item.open.Ticks*10 })
        .Concat(eList.Select(item => new { t = "close", d = item.close, s = (item.close.Ticks*10)+1 }))
        .OrderBy(item => item.s);

  var max = datelist.Aggregate(
            new { curCount = 0, max = 0 },
            (result,item) => {
               if (item.t == "open")
               {
                  if (result.max < (result.curCount+1))
                    return(new { curCount = result.curCount+1, max = result.curCount+1 });
                  else
                    return(new { curCount = result.curCount+1, max = result.max });
               }
               else
                 return(new { curCount = result.curCount-1, max = result.max });
            },
            result => result.max);

   max.Dump();
}

// Define other methods and classes here

public class Event
{
    public DateTime open { get; set; }
    public DateTime close { get; set; }

    public Event(DateTime inOpen, DateTime inClose)
    {
      if (inOpen <= inClose)
      {
        open = inOpen;
        close = inClose;
      }
      else throw(new Exception("Can't close at "+inClose.ToShortDateString()+" before you open at "+inOpen.ToShortDateString()));
    }
}
```

Comment: Yep, I see now. I assume it's `O(n logn)` though, since it's implemented as a stable quicksort

Comment: As an alternative you could also transform it to the list of `open`, `close` strings (or bools, or whatever) and on each open `++` the counter, and `--` on each `close`. Remembering the maximum reached value

Comment: Wow, thanks everybody for your answers, this one works great! +1, accept and more if I could :) Big thanks!

Comment: @zerkms: I'm sorry but this one gives me the correct number of open events and your returns a few more (even if I don't know why). But +1 on yours as well :)

Comment: @Marc: my works inclusively, this one - exclusively. so for intervals `1-2; 2-3` my would return 2, this - 1. So the obvious solution - use `<` instead of `<=` for mine, the same for `>`

Comment: @zerkms actually mine should be inclusive.  That was the point of the `s` attribute, to make all closes greater than opens.  However, I had a bug -- Union instead of Concat.  With concat I think this will give the same results.

Comment: @Hogan: seems like 2 bugs annihilated :-) (since the solution with a typo gave an expected results)

Answer (score 1):

```
var max = events.Select(i => events.Where(j => i.DateOpen <= j.DateClose
                                            && i.DateClose >= j.DateOpen).Count())
                .Max();
```

But it's of a complexity `O(n^2)` which may not be suitable for all cases

Cannot think of a faster solution though at the moment.

Comment: You can do it in O(N lg(N)) by sorting the open and close times and then walking them in order keeping track of the current number of open events (and maximum number of open events).

Comment: @Gabe: "walking them in order keeping track of the current number of open events" --- and this is the issue, isn't it?

Comment: Thank you very much! I just tried it but it gives me more open events than there are (but I have to double check to make sure it's not my mistake in the data).

Comment: @zerkms - not so hard with Aggregate, see my answer

Answer (score 0):

Since the actual answer is in a comment only:

```
events.Select(i => events.Where(j => i.DateOpen <= j.DateClose && i.DateClose >= j.DateOpen).Count()).Max()
```